# Rule optimizer to inject synthetic merge keys when joining on specific relationship

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have custom relationship function (let's call it `SPEC.relate(a, b)`) that I want to optimize with an injected rule. I'm hoping to just rewrite the logical plan rather than implement my own `*Exec` physical plan.

Given the following...

```scala
a.join(b, SPEC.relate(a.col("spec_field"), b.col("spec_field")))
```

`a.spec_field` and `b.spec_field` can map to one or more keys (yes there are duplicates across keys)

The optimized version looks something like this...

```scala
a_with_key = a.withColumn("synth_key", F.explode(SPEC.generate_key_array("spec_field")))
b_with_key = b.withColumn("synth_key", F.explode(SPEC.generate_key_array("spec_field")))

a_with_key.join(b_with_key, "synth_key")
  .where(SPEC.relate(a_with_key.col("spec_field"), b_with_key.col("spec_field")))
```

My thinking is as follows but I can't quite figure out what I need to do to the logical plan to make it happen.

```scala
object SpecRelateRule extends Rule[LogicalPlan] {
  override def apply(plan: LogicalPlan): LogicalPlan = plan.transform {
    case x @ Join(left, right, joinType, condition @ Some(SPEC.relate(leftExpr, rightExpr)), hint) =>
      // TODO can I do the following?
      // leftKeys = left.withColumn("synth_key", F.explode(SPEC.generate_key_array(leftExpr)))
      // rightKeys = right.withColumn("synth_key", F.explode(SPEC.generate_key_array(rightExpr)))
      // joined = Join(leftKeys, rightKeys, joinType, condition, StrategyHint("merge", "synth_key"))
      // somehow drop join key
  }
}
```

Comment: not an expert here, but I don't think putting that explode there is a good idea. In cases when there is no 1 to many mapping, the explode is still a part of the plan and will be executed. Depending on what Spec does, i will recommend to break it down to a 1 to 1 mapping. But I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Right. The actual implementation of the spec function will only expand when needed. The example is just to show the gist of the issue.